# Emulating the Vista/W7 "search bar" in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp

One of the greatest UI features in Vista is the ability to hit Windows key, start typing the name of a program, hit enter, and it **runs**.

I want to be able to do this in XP. Is there a nifty program to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there's [Launchy](http://www.launchy.net/).

I personally haven't used it, but it seems to be highly recommended.

Answer (score 2):

**[ViStart](http://lee-soft.com/vistart/#features)** - the Vista Start Menu for XP.

> **Launch Programs faster then ever before**
>
> ViStart dramatically decreases the
>   time taken to search for programs by
>   indexing your program shortcuts. Then
>   you can simply type part of the
>   program into the start menu and
>   ViStart will "instantly" find it.
>
> **Find files faster than Vista**
>
> ViStart not only indexes programs but
>   also files as well. Just type the file
>   you are looking for and in miliseconds
>   ViStart will return results (Up to 4
>   times faster than the orignal Vista
>   start menu!).

[image]

ViStart is freeware

Answer (score 1):

This could be the solution you're looking for

http://www.launchy.net/

Answer (score 0):

Press Win+R.  The Run dialog appears.  Type the name of the program you want to run and Enter.

The first time you run a particular program you need to type its full name, but after you have run a program once, Windows will remember it.  For instance, I often run CMD.EXE from the Run dialog.  I press Win+R, then "c" and a dropdown list of all programs I've ever run from this dialog whose names begin with "c" appears.  Down-arrow and Enter and CMD.EXE is running.

Comment: the chief issue is that is not as "loose" in the name. IE, I can type "chrome", and Vista finds "Google Chrome". Whereas Run requires the actual executable name.

Comment: I use a  file with `@echo off
echo "@ECHO OFF 
%2 %%^*" > c:\aliases\%1.bat
echo Aliased %1 to %2`. I called it alias.bat ;)